# BroadcastReceiver onReceive is called immediately or not at all

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm writing an app with a fixed time auto-logout function.
Here is the code:

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    [...]>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    [...]
    <receiver
        android:name="myPackage.LoginAlarm">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="myPackage.ACTION_LOGOUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Activity (from onActivityResult, after a successful login):

```
if(session.getUser().length() > 0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getResources().getString(R.string.action_logout));
    i.setClass(this, LoginAlarm.class);
    this.sendBroadcast(i);

    al.setOwner(this); // LoginAlarm instance, setting context.
    al.setAlarm(this, i);
}
```

LoginAlarm class:

```
public class LoginAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final static long LIMIT = 600000; // session timeout, 10 minutes.
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    private StartAct owner;

    public LoginAlarm() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Log.i("LoginAlarm", "onReceive: time out.");
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(alarmMgr != null) alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);

        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, 0);

        long trigger = System.currentTimeMillis() + LIMIT;
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, trigger, alarmIntent);

        String click = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        String end = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(trigger));
        Log.i("LoginAlarm", "setAlarm: Click at: " + click + ". Alarm set: " + end);
    }
}
```

If in my Activity I comment the line:

```
   this.sendBroadcast(i);
```

**onReceive** is never called, but with this line the method is called immediately after the alarm is set, no matter how long the LIMIT is.

Please, I read tons of articles, tutorials and posts with no luck so far.

Need some hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An `ELAPSED_REALTIME` alarm is based on the time since the last boot, but you're setting it with a "wall clock" time, so it's _waaay_ in the future. You can either use an `RTC*` alarm, or figure the alarm time with `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm not sure I understood your words. I'm aware that System.currentTimeMillis() can be swayed by tampering the clock time, but in my tests I'm not.

From the Logcat: 

`05-18 09:04:17.326 12684-12684/mdn.arpoid I/LoginAlarm: setAlarm: Click at: 2018-05-18 09:04:17.
Alarm set: 2018-05-18 09:05:17 05-18 09:04:17.466 12684-12684/mdn.arpoid I/LoginAlarm: onReceive: time out.`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that the Logcat above is coming out after I changed the line below, to follow your suggestion.
`alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger, alarmIntent);`

Comment: It's nothing to do with tampering with anything, but I'm not sure how else to explain it. An `ELAPSED_REALTIME` alarm uses the system clock that starts over each time you reboot. For example, say you just rebooted 100000ms ago, and you set an alarm like in your snippet above. The time you pass there is going to be at least 1526629497000ms, which, you can see, is a huge difference, like >48 years. Anyway, your `onReceive()` log looks like it fired there, so you good now?

Comment: Ok, I got it.

Correct me if I'm wrong, you are saying that the starting point is like 100000 ms ago, but the trigger time is the limit I set PLUS the time coming from `System.currentTimeMillis()`, that's starting at 1970.

Great hint, thanks, so why `onReceive` is fire immediately? I'd expect to wait 48 years...

Comment: "you are saying that the starting point is like 100000 ms ago, but the trigger time is the limit I set PLUS the time coming from System.currentTimeMillis(), that's starting at 1970." – Right, when you use `ELAPSED_REALTIME`, that's basically the situation. "why `onReceive` is fire immediately?" – I'm not really sure what your current setup is, but if an alarm fires immediately, it means that it was set for a time in the past. Debug to check your times, and make sure you're not confusing the alarm with that `sendBroadcast(i)` you've got in the posted code.

Comment: Got it!!!

After some other reading and your advices I finally got it working.
Thanks, mate! It looks like I cannot up-vote your comments, sorry, but I owe you one ^_^